# styled component doesn't work with hierachy selectors

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I'm learning to use styled components,but it looks like when i target `css classes in hierarchy`,it doesn't seem to work.Here i'm using i would like to make apply some styles wheneve use hovers on navigations links.
Here is my navbar code :

```
import React from "react";
import { Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import Flag from "../common/Image";
import styled from "styled-components";
import NavLink from "../common/NavLink";

const imageURL = "/static/img/abc.png";

const Navigation = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    <Navbar className={className} collapseOnSelect expand="lg" variant="light">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
        <Flag imageSource={imageURL} size={[80, 70]} />
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <NavLink linkName="A" URL={"#"} />
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <NavLink linkName="B" URL={"#a"} />
          <NavLink linkName="C" URL={"#b"} />
          <NavLink linkName="D" URL={"#b"} />
        </Nav>
        <Nav>
          <NavLink linkName="Espace de discussion" URL={"#discussions"} />
          <NavLink linkName="Contactez-nous" URL={"#contact"} />
          <Nav.Link>
            <i clasName="fas fa-envelope" />
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link>
            <i className="fas fa-bell" />
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link>
            <i className="fas fa-user-circle" />
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default styled(Navigation)`
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e8f0;
`;
```

And my `NavLink component`

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const NavLink = ({ linkName, URL, className }) => {
  return (
    <Nav.Link className={className} href={URL}>
      {linkName}
    </Nav.Link>
  );
};

NavLink.PropTypes = {
  linkName: PropTypes.string,
  URL: PropTypes.string
};



export default styled(NavLink)`
  cursor: pointer;
  color: green;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  padding: 10px;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    font-size: 90;
    background-color: #2e384d;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link &:hover {
    color: white;
  }
`;
```

I the bellow `gif`,the animation is for changind links styled is working for all the links,but the color is only changing to `white` for the `A` link.But the form other background,border are changing but not the link color.Here the behaviour:
[image: Gif animation]
When i use the following code : `.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link &:hover {
        color: white;
      }` in a normal `css` file without using styled component i get the good the exptected behavior.For solving i tried to use `sass` way of doing in the definition of my styled component like this :

```
.navbar-light {
    .navbar-nav {
      .nav-link {
        &:hover {
          color: white;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But nothing changes.How can i do for making all links text become white with `styled-compont` definition?

Comment: Use the `&` sass selector. For example: `& .navbar-light > .navbar-nav > .nav-link:hover { color: white;}` or simply: `& .nav-link:hover { color: white; }`. When working with styled-components, any selected children classes should initially start with `& .className`. I believe, if you use class scopes `{ }`, and you want to target their children, then they'll also need the `& .className` as well.

Comment: Thank you but,the problems is still there

Comment: One moment, I'll see if I can create a codesandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, because of how `<Nav>` is wrapping your `<NavLink>`, the `nav-link` className has a higher specificity than your styled component className (the NavLink component is applying the styled component className before "nav-link" and, as a result, doesn't override the Bootstrap CSS). For example, the className looks like: "sc-lhVmIH gcJAof nav-link", where the styled component className: "sc-lhVmIH gcJAof" is being overridden by the last applied className "nav-link". There are several solutions to fix this, as shown below.

---

## Solutions

1. Simply add `color: white !important;` in the styled NavLink:

```
export default styled(NavLink)`
  cursor: pointer;
  color: green;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;

  &:hover {
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 90;
    background-color: #2e384d;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
`;
```

2. In Navigation, where `<NavBar className={className}>...</NavBar>` accepts a styled component className, add the following css to override the Bootstrap CSS stylesheet:

```
export default styled(Navigation)`
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e8f0;

  &.navbar-light {
    & .navbar-nav {
      & .nav-link:hover {
        color: white;
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

3. Import the Bootstrap less into a less file and override the `nav-link:hover` className.

---

## CSS Specificity

**Here's how the CSS specificity is being applied to the DOM**:

[image]

---

## Demos

Click [here](https://bxk11.csb.app) for a working demo.

Working codesandbox (contains solution #1 and #2 -- you'll only need to use **one** of them, not both):

[image: Edit Styled SVG Component]