# With Styled Components how to style parent based on child having aria-current page or a particular className?

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, styled-components, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Trying to style a parent div for a child's `Link` if the `Link` has the applied `aria-current="page"` or an `active` class name.

code (stripped):

```
<NavBody>
  {items.map((subItem, key) => {
    const { title, link } = subItem
    return (
      <NavLinkContainer key={key}>
        <NavLink
          onClick={closeMobileMenu}
          to={`/docs${link}`}
          activeClassName="active"
        >
          {title}
        </NavLink>
      </NavLinkContainer>
    )
  })}
</NavBody>
```

Styled Components:

```
const NavBody = styled(Accordion.Body)`
  margin-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.small};
  padding: 0 !important;
`

const NavLinkContainer = styled.div`
  padding-top: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.xSmall};
  padding-bottom: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.xSmall};
  border-left: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color7};
  padding-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.small} !important;
`

const NavLink = styled(Link)`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color3};
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.xxSmall};

  &.active {
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color1};
  }

  &:hover {
    color: inherit;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color1};
  }
`
```

I tried:

```
const NavLinkContainer = styled.div`
  padding-top: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.xSmall};
  padding-bottom: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.xSmall};
  border-left: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color7};
  padding-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.small} !important;

  &.active {
    border-left: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color1};
  }
`
```

but that's incorrectly applied due to the `padding-left`. Another attempt:

```
<NavBody>
  {items.map((subItem, key) => {
    const { title, link } = subItem
    return (
      <NavLinkContainer key={key} activeClassName="active">
        <NavLink
          onClick={closeMobileMenu}
          to={`/docs${link}`}
          activeClassName="active"
        >
          {title}
        </NavLink>
      </NavLinkContainer>
    )
  })}
</NavBody>
```

the applied `activeClassName` doesn't render on the `div` and:

```
const NavLinkContainer = styled.div`
  padding-top: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.xSmall};
  padding-bottom: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.xSmall};
  border-left: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color7};
  padding-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.small} !important;

  &[aria-current='page'] {
    border-left: 3px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color1} !important;
  }
`
```

doesn't render the color.

### Research

- [Styled Components: How to target direct children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690167/styled-components-how-to-target-direct-children)
- [Styled-Components: specify styles of children on parents hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036382/styled-components-specify-styles-of-children-on-parents-hover)
- [How to add an aria attribute to a styled component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083705/how-to-add-an-aria-attribute-to-a-styled-component)
- [Style a component's [aria-checked="true"] using Material UI's makeStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62271948/style-a-components-aria-checked-true-using-material-uis-makestyle)
- [styled component doesn't work with hierachy selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232729/styled-component-doesnt-work-with-hierachy-selectors)

In Styled Components is there a way to style the parent based wether the child has a className of `active` or `aria-current="page"`?

Comment: It's impossible in css so probably impossible in styled-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to modify my parent `NavLinkContainer`. In Reach Router I have access to `pathname` from [`useLocation`](https://reach.tech/router/api/useLocation):

```
const { pathname } = useLocation()
```

using `link` from my map and [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) I was able to find if the `link` existed by setting to a variable:

```
const active = useMemo(() => {
    return pathname.toString().includes(link)
  }, [pathname, link])
```

by doing so I could pass a boolean to `NavLinkContainer`:

```
<NavLinkContainer border={active}>
  // Further code
</NavLinkContainer>
```

and in the Styled Component I could do:

```
const NavLinkContainer = styled.div`
  border-color: ${({ border, theme }) =>
    border ? `${theme.colors.color1}` : `${theme.colors.color5}`};
`
```

which gives me the ability to style the parent `div` with a custom border color set within my theme.